# Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation failed : growing buffer

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have large `xlsx` file. which i want to read(used PHPExcel) in one array and load that array in mysql database. when i am loading small xlsx file for same code it is work fine but for large file given **Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation failed : growing buffer**

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify('mylarge.xlsx');

                $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);  

                $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

                /**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/  
                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('mylarge.xlsx');

                $total_sheets=$objPHPExcel->getSheetCount(); 

                $allSheetName=$objPHPExcel->getSheetNames(); 
                $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 
                $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); 
                $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();  
                $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);  
                for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) 
                {  
                    for ($col = 0; $col <$highestColumnIndex; ++$col)
                    {  
                            $value=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();  

                            $arraydata[$row-1][$col]=$value; 


                    }  

                }



        print_r($arraydata);

?>
```

mylarge.xlsx file contain `700000` rows.

can any one tell me how to solve this problem.

thank you.

Comment: If you're working with large volumes of data in memory, then you really should set your php.ini memory allowance to a high enough level... try enabling PHPExcel's cell caching options to reduce memory usage

Comment: @Mark Baker please can you tell me how to do that.

Comment: There's a whole section of the documentation dedicated to cell caching: section 4.2.1 of the developer documentation; or [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md) in the [online documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation)

Comment: You can also eliminate looping through the cells building your array by using the worksheet's toArray() method... but building an in memory array as you're doing is also going to use a lot of memory for a large worksheet

Comment: @Mark Baker  thank you. i have used all cell caching method but it not working.

Comment: In that case, you will certainly need to increase the amount of memory that is allocated to PHP in your php.ini file

Comment: ya i did memory_limit = -1 in php.ini.

Comment: I had similar problem and explore many solutions but nothing worked except this one https://github.com/box/spout really worked for me with 140K rows about 18MB file.

Comment: Here is worked solution for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966439/reading-large-excel-file-with-php/36486988#36486988