# Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation failed : growing buffer

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

Following code is used to convert an XLSX file to CSV using PHPExcel:

```
  <?php
    require_once 'PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    $excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("test123.xlsx");
    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');
    $writer->setDelimiter(";");
    $writer->setEnclosure("");
    $writer->save("test123.csv");
    ?>
```

I am trying to convert large excel file, 70MB in size, to CSV. I am getting this error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
```

I have increased `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit=-1` in php.ini.

Can anyone please tell me why this error is getting where am i going wrong?

Comment: Here is worked solution for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966439/reading-large-excel-file-with-php/36486988#36486988

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are few suggestions for you:

1. If your xlsx have more than one sheet and you need only one or few of them, then try to load only that.
2. Use [Cell caching](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md).
3. You can also eliminate looping through the cells building your array by using the worksheet's `toArray()` method.

Try combinations or all of the above mentioned suggestions and see if it can help you. Also, refer [this](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/242712) discussion from forum.

```
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_in_memory_gzip;
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod);
```

refer [this](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md#phpexcel_cachedobjectstoragefactorycache_in_memory_gzip) and the description below to understand it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.We have only one sheet in excel file and its around 70MB. May i know how to use this just we have include $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_in_memory;

PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod); or what i have to do?

Comment: @GajananHiroji: I have updated answer. Check it now.

Comment: Hey Bhavik, i did whatever you said but i am getting this error  Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
 PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 615

Comment: here you go ....  $xmlSheet = simplexml_load_string($this->_getFromZipArchive($zip, "$dir/$fileWorksheet"));  //~