# PhpSpreadsheet: Warning simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation failed : growing buffer

Tags: php, xampp, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am facing below issue when i read excel file using "PHP Spread Sheet" libary of 1 lack rows.

Can you please advise what is issue or how can i solve?

> PhpSpreadsheet: Warning simplexml_load_string(): Memory allocation
>   failed : growing buffer in
>   phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx.php on line
>   756

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading large excel file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966439/reading-large-excel-file-with-php)

Comment: @AymDev one more thing can we read data of excel by row?